# Extensions of diffeomorphisms of $S^2$ and the connectedness of $\text{Diff}^+(S^2)$

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology

In [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80846/extending-a-diffeomorphism-of-s2-to-d3) by Daniel Moskovich, he claims that the fact that every diffeomorphism of $S^2$ extends to a diffeomorphism of $D^3$ implies that $\text{Diff}^+(S^2)$, the group of orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms of the 2-sphere) is connected.

Why does this follow? It doesn't seem obvious to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any orientation-preserving diffeomorphism $f$ of a star-shaped subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is isotopic to the identity. To see this, show $f$ is isotopic to $df_0$ (assuming the region is star-shaped with respect to $0$ and $f(0)=0$), and then it's a standard linear algebra exercise that $GL(n,\Bbb R)^+$ is connected.

To see the first step, you want to use the usual $C^\infty$ trick and write $$f(x)=\sum x_i g_i(x), \quad\text{where } g(0) = df_0.$$

Comment: This does not answer the question. The diffeomorphic extension of a diffeomorphism of the sphere to $D^{n+1}$ will give you an isotopy between the diffeomorphism od $S^n$ and the identity through embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. However we need an isotopy of diffeomorphisms of $S^n$.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Yes, I agree. This post is almost 10 years old, so who knows what we were thinking. Offhand, now, it seems that we can just project the isotopy back to the sphere.